# How to place text over different images with different positions?

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, css-position

I know how to place text over 1 image by giving the image `position:relative;` and the text `position:absolute;` and then position the text where I want. My problem is that I have a list of images on which I want to place a text. The solution I mentioned doesn't work, because when I try to position the text, all of them will have the same position and I see only one text. I'm sure you understand what I mean. Is there a solution for this only by using CSS?

**edit:** I should mention that this is a vertical list and all the images have the same `left`.
**edit 2:** They the text and the image are already in a container!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should nest your image and Text in a container(a div). You then position the text in the div and the image in the div. This should solve your problem.

here is my working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kqYcT/

`.image_container{ position: relative; }`

```
.image_container img{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 1;
 }

.text{
   position:absolute;
   top: 70px;
   left: 35px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
  }
```

Comment: They're already in a container. I tried giving the image a z-index and position it with both absolute and normal position, but I can't get it to work. I'm waiting for your example, thanks.

Comment: Ha ha. Almost the same answer at the same time. :)

Comment: I just posted a jsfiddle where you can view my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The css "`position: relative`" modifies the target elements position RELATIVE to the parent container. The solution is to put both items inside a parent container. You "bind" the text and image together in a wrapper container.

Here's a jsfiddle for you to see:
http://jsfiddle.net/r2rCt/1/

eg:

```
<div>
<div class="text" style="position: relative; top: 20px; right: 20px;">Text</div>
    <img src="<your img URL>"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't mind I'll accept Stefan's answer, because he was making the example :) Will upvote yours of course!

Comment: Good for me. Just here to help (and trying to get an answer in before the 1000s of other great developers on this site is tricky! :)